# I would like to have a single WHERE in this Condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem in my MySQL, I have 3 combo box and I wanted to get their value so I can create a filter for them. I wanted to have 1 `where` for these codes, so can anyone help me. TIA

```
if($this->input->get('name')) 
            $name = $this->input->get('name');
        else   
            $name =  "";
        $namecondition = "";
            if(strlen($name) > 0)
                $namecondition .= "WHERE E.`nameid` = '$name'";

        if($this->input->get('age')) 
            $age = $this->input->get('age');
        else   
            $age =  "";
        $namecondition2 = "";
            if(strlen($age) > 0)
                $namecondition2 .= "WHERE E.`ageid` = '$name'";

        if($this->input->get('year')) 
            $year = $this->input->get('year');
        else   
            $year =  "";
        $namecondition = "";
            if(strlen($year) > 0)
                $namecondition3 .= "WHERE E.`yearid` = '$name'";            

        $sSQL = "SELECT *,COALESCE(E.`id`,0) AS 'eid'
                 FROM employee AS E
                 LEFT JOIN name AS B ON E.nameid = B.id
                 LEFT JOIN age AS C ON E.ageid = C.id
                 LEFT JOIN year AS J ON E.yearid = J.id
                 $namecondition
                 ORDER BY E.lastName ASC";
```

Comment: any particular reason why u want to have single `where` clause??? current SQL looks fine to me!!

Comment: I will create a filter based on the values of the three combo boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution use `where 1=1` and append your another string starting by `AND`...

```
if($this->input->get('name')) 
        $name = $this->input->get('name');
    else   
        $name =  "";
    $namecondition = "";
        if(strlen($name) > 0)
            $namecondition .= " AND E.`nameid` = '$name'";

    if($this->input->get('age')) 
        $age = $this->input->get('age');
    else   
        $age =  "";
    $namecondition2 = "";
        if(strlen($age) > 0)
            $namecondition2 .= " AND E.`ageid` = '$name'";

    if($this->input->get('year')) 
        $year = $this->input->get('year');
    else   
        $year =  "";
    $namecondition = "";
        if(strlen($year) > 0)
            $namecondition3 .= " AND E.`yearid` = '$name'";            

    $sSQL = "SELECT *,COALESCE(E.`id`,0) AS 'eid'
             FROM employee AS E
             LEFT JOIN name AS B ON E.nameid = B.id
             LEFT JOIN age AS C ON E.ageid = C.id
             LEFT JOIN year AS J ON E.yearid = J.id
             where 1 = 1 
             $namecondition
             ORDER BY E.lastName ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect those WHEREs, you need AND instead of WHERE each time. And use only a single `$namecondition` variable to build the where string (no `$namecondition2` and `$namecondition3`).

So you can do something like this. Start with a dummy one as a default:

```
$namecondition = "WHERE 1 ";
```

And the for each concatation use AND:

```
$namecondition .= " AND E.`nameid` = '$name'";
```

etc...

This will create: `WHERE 1 AND first_condition AND second_condition...`.